# Loop cut stops at quad

Tags: edges, loop

How come this loop won't connect all the way around? The direction and topology seems to be correct. There are 6 vertices selected here with a box select, and I've done "Merge by distance" to make sure there are no odd vertices

[image]

Comment: so there might be an inner face?

Comment: Check for the following: duplicated geometry, disconnected faces, a possible n-gon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the pointers in the comments. Turns out I screwed up during retopo.

This was one face. The edge across was not connected to the faces, i.e. splitting them.

Found the issue by selecting faces and comparing the count to what I was seeing. I suppose this is exactly what @susu meant with "disconnected faces", so cheers

[image]

I solved it by deleting the face and filling in between the edges to create the two faces I expected

Comment: Yes, sometimes you can have faces that share the same vertices but are not connected to each other, as they have different edges. A tool to use in such cases is "dissolve edges" instead of deleting the faces.

Comment: You are absolutely right. While fixing topology, I should have dissolved edges rather than delete them. Thanks :)